# Do routers generate and send packets that are larger than 1500Bytes? (like RIP packets which are only send to routers)

Tags: networking, router

And if they do, since the MTU of Ethernet is 1500Bytes, does this mean routers should and can reassemble packets?

because I always thought routers don't bother with reassembling packets, but if some of the packets which are generated by routers and send directly to routers should be reassembled when they arrive at router?

(again, I'm talking about packets which are directed at routers like routing packets such as RIP or spanning tree packets in cisco  )

Comment: You'd be better off asking this on serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"MTU" is a layer 3 term, so it's rather "the MTU *for IP over Ethernet* is 1500 byte".

A RIP datagram is allowed to hold up to 25 entries of 44 bytes each - so unless an Ethernet link carries a rather excessive overhead (the RIP datagram would need to go through multiple, nested tunnels), the datagram will easily fit in a single frame. Although this isn't detailed in RFC 2453, I don't think a router would ever build a RIP datagram exceeding the destination link's MTU (requiring fragmenting) but simple send multiple datagrams.

Comment: So overall routers do not need and cant  reassemble received packets, correct?

Comment: No, usually they don't reassemble fragmented packets but forward the fragments separately.